# How can I move the button in the middle in html?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have my code like this, and I tried several times to move the button to the middle but failed. How should I modify the code to change the location of the button? It was always in the far left. Thanks!

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 align="center">Bucket List App</h1>
    <p class="lead"></p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="showSignUp" role="button" style="width:200px">Sign up today</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use flex classes `d-flex justify-content-center`. Check out code below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 align="center">Bucket List App</h1>
    <p class="lead"></p>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
     <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="showSignUp" role="button" style="width:200px">Sign up today</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to align all elements you can add `d-flex flex-column align-items-center` classes to jumbotron. It depends on what you need.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="jumbotron d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
  <h1>Bucket List App</h1>
  <p class="lead"></p>
  <div>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="showSignUp" role="button" style="width:200px">Sign up today</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have already used `align="center"`to center h1 just u can use the same concept to move the button to the middle.

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 align="center">Bucket List App</h1>
    <p class="lead"></p>
    <p align="center"><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="showSignUp" role="button" style="width:200px">Sign up today</a></p>
</div>
```

**But align attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.**

just add `class="text-center"` to move the button to the middle(center).
I hope this will help you:

To know more:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="text-center">Bucket List App</h1>
    <p class="lead"></p>
    <p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="showSignUp" role="button" style="width:200px">Sign up today</a></p>
</div>
```